# Session expiring too quickly Liberty Profile

Tags: jsf, session-timeout, websphere-liberty

I'm having some trouble regarding the session timeout configuration of my JSF 2.2 web application deployed on Websphere Liberty Profile 17.0.0.1.

Sometimes (it's an intermittent behavior) after just 1 minute of inactivity the session expires.

I have configured this on my server.xml:

```
    <httpSession cookieHttpOnly="false" cookieName="FGI_JSESSION_ID"  
idReuse="true" invalidationTimeout="15m" 
invalidateOnUnauthorizedSessionRequestException="true"/>
    <ltpa expiration="15m" 
keysFileName="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/ltpa.keys" />
```

In addition, I have put this on my web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

The idea was to have a 15-minute-timeout. Does anyone know where I might be missing it?

Thank you

Comment: How do you know the session expires? Can it be that there is a problem with a cookie so the server cannot match/find an existing session? The reason I ask this is that 'intermittent' [behavio**U**r  ;-)](http://grammarist.com/spelling/behavior-behaviour/) is most likely not caused by a configuration error. And try with a plain jsp or something. JSF does effectively not know about sessions and just uses what the container provides

Comment: your session timeout settings in server.xml looks valid. Are there any firewalls configured that is causing this behavior ?